# pygame.mixer.music; music crackles when playing ogg files

Tags: pygame, playback

I can get the music to play but when it loops, if it's an .ogg file there's always a noticeable crackle noise. The crackling or clicking noise doesn't occur when an .mp3 or a .wav is looped, only .ogg files.

If I convert an .ogg file to .mp3 using Audacity, there's no crackle noise when it loops. I've tried looking for answers to this but nothing I've found works.

```
import pygame, sys, pygame.mixer
from pygame.locals import *


WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 2, 2048) 
pygame.init()
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((300,400))

pygame.mixer.music.load('data/Acrostics.ogg')
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1) 

while True:
    DISPLAYSURF.fill(WHITE)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Perhaps it is an issue of streaming the OGG file with `pygame.mixer.music`.  Have you tried using `pygame.mixer.Sound` to have the OGG completely loaded before playing?

Comment: Also, if possible have you tried converting an MP3 to an OGG?  From what I've read, OGG doesn't use low-pass filtering, while MP3 does, so sometimes converting an OGG file to MP3 removes popping or crackling.

Answer (score 1):

Before `pygame.init()`

Try `pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 2, 1024)`

Or you can also instead try : `pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 2, 4096)`

Comment: @Haz I have tried converting an mp3 to ogg and the cracking is still there. In regards to monkey's suggestion, I've also tried both 1024 and 4096 as the buffer size and neither worked. 
Converting an ogg to mp3 and back again to ogg removed the crackle noise, but there is a very brief pop noise before it loops again.